# Replace a matrix by a diagonal matrix using a predefined list using Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have a vector say which I want to use to form a vector of diagonal matrices 
as follows

```
     double shapes=[2,3,4,5];
     Vector2d temp;
     std::vector<Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 2> > diavector;
     diavector.resize(4);

     for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       temp<<shapes[i],shapes[i];
       diavector[i]=temp.asDiagonal();
       cout<<diavector[i].toDenseMatrix()<<endl; 
     }
```

I now have a larger Matrices say

```
    Eigen::MatrixXd N(2,12);
    N.setZero(2,12);
```

I now want to place the elements of the diavector into suitable positions of the N matrix according to a preassigned list. for example if

```
   double listIndices={0,2,3,5}
```

which gives the position of the vector where the block 
matrices have to be inserted to get a matrix N like

```
     N=[2 0 0 0 3 0 4 0 0 0 5 0 
        0 2 0 0 0 3 0 4 0 0 0 5]
```

How do go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `N.middleCols(listIndices[i]*stride, stride) = temp.asDiagonal()`, where, for your example, `stride` equals 2.